# Is there a simpler way to do the if else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's been a month since I study the web mapping. I'm currently practicing jQuery` and GeoServer.

Is there a way I to simplify it? Can I use `switch` here?

```
bridge.on('change:visible', function(){
    if(bridge.getVisible() == true) {
        $('#bridge').show();                        
    } else {
        $('#bridge').hide();
    }
});

road.on('change:visible', function(){
    if(road.getVisible() == true) {
        $('#road').show();                      
    } else {
        $('#road').hide();
    }
});

rail.on('change:visible', function(){
    if(rail.getVisible() == true) {
        $('#rail').show();                      
    } else {
        $('#rail').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: *"Can I use switch here?"* You can always use a `switch` instead of an `if/else`, but that doesn't mean you *should*. In this case you can replace the whole if/else with `$("#bridge").toggle(bridge.getVisible())`. (Or possibly `$("#bridge").toggle(bridge.getVisible() == true)` if there's a chance `.getVisible()` might return something other than a boolean.)

Comment: If `rail` and `#rail` are the same object, then use you can use `this`. Otherwise, you can use data-attributes to make classes behave similarly, but on different targets. But it is unclear - what is `rail`, `road`, `bridge`? Could you show the HTML? (Only related to this code)

Comment: Is `on("change:visible")` a valid syntax? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: [Good reading here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) on the `[condition] ? [do if true] : [do if false]` syntax.

Comment: Can you not use `$().toggle()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't really with the if-else-statement that needs simplification, it's the [repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Wrap the repeated code in a function, factor the differences into parameters, and call it thrice:

```
function toggleWithVisibility(source, target) {
    source.on('change:visible', function(){
        if (source.getVisible() == true) {
            target.show();                        
        } else {
            target.hide();
        }
    });
}
toggleWithVisibility(bridge, $('#bridge'));
toggleWithVisibility(road, $('#road'));
toggleWithVisibility(rail, $('#rail'));
```

You also can simplify the functions code by omitting the superfluous `== true` and by using [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) with an argument:

```
function toggleWithVisibility(source, target) {
    source.on('change:visible', function(){
        target.toggle(source.getVisible());
    });
}
```

You didn't yet show us how your three variables are defined, chances are good you might be able to simplify those as well, e.g. selecting `source` and `target` together and by calling the function from a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Embrace the functional!

```
function toggleVisible(thing, selector){
  selector.toggle(thing.getVisible());
}

 bridge.on('change:visible', toggleVisible.bind(this, bridge, $('#bridge'));
 road.on('change:visible', toggleVisible.bind(this, road, $('#road'));
 rail.on('change:visible', toggleVisible.bind(this, rail, $('#rail'));
```

Comment: you do because i am setting the visiblity to the parameter passed in. It could be the case that other events are affecting the show/hide behaviour and we simply want to set the visibility instead of changing its state

Comment: `Toggle` expects `duration` as first args. `getVisible` will return boolean which in turn will get converted to `0` or `1`

Comment: @Rajesh - No, `.toggle()` *also* accepts a boolean as first argument for show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single `jQuery()` call, `.on()`, and conditional operator, `.filter()`

```
$("#bridge, #road, #rail").on("change:visible", function() {
  $(this).toggle(!$(this).getVisible());
});
```

Comment: Note that the OP's three functions don't all update `#road`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Missed that

Comment: I suspect appropriate use of `this` would solve the problem, but it's unclear if `bridge` and `#bridge` are the same element, so...

Comment: Not the voter, but you have complicated a lot in my understanding. Also `.toggle` does `[curr.getVisible() ? "show" : "hide"]()`, so you should use it

Comment: @Rajesh Not certain how code appears more complicated when there is less overall code? Yes, could alternatively use `curr.toggle()`

Comment: I didn't vote, but the code looks more complicated to me to. Shorter, sure, but harder to read than the original. The question doesn't say if `bridge` and `#bridge` are the same element, but if they *are* then you don't need the `.is("#bridge")` ternary, you could then just say `curr = $(this)` or use your existing `el` instead of `curr`.

Comment: Double ternary, kill me now.

Comment: @nnnnnn At one could not gather conditional operator at all. Now, use the operator for cases like the current Question. Cannot make everyone happy

Comment: @AndyGaskell What is issue with nested conditional operator?

Comment: I like the conditional operator in a general sense. But in this example it seems a bit tautological - the result of the statement is kind of just to assign `curr = el`.

Comment: @guest271314 more than one ternary per line severely damages readability IMO. (I'm not your downvoter, just my two cents)

Comment: Yes, to determine `el` where OP has not clarified if `bridge` is `#bridge`. The code appears complicated yet "tautological" is used to describe the code. Cannot and do not try to fit into popular or unpopular style conventions. Just the way compose some solutions.

Comment: @AndyGaskell Disagree. But cannot judge how another evaluates "readability"

Comment: `elems.filter(this)` doesn't really make sense. If I understand [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) correctly, it would be equivalent to `$(this)` (given that `this` is always part of `elems`)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $list= ["bridge", "road","rail"];


$list.forEach(function(v) {
   if($('#'+v').is(":visible")) {
            $('#'+v').show();                      
        } else {
            $('#'+v').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: bridge, road and rail are variables though so unfortunately this won't bind the 'change:visible' event

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it!

```
    bridge.on('change:visible', function(){
        $('#bridge').toggle();
    });

    road.on('change:visible', function(){
         $('#road').toggle();
    });

    rail.on('change:visible', function(){
         $('#rail').toggle();
    });
```

Comment: Please check other answers before you post.

Comment: That might get out of sync easily.